# Extracting likelihoods from generative model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, inference, quantiles, generative-models

I am looking for papers dealing with the extraction of explicit descriptions of probability distributions from a generative model. My use case is the following: I trained a GAN to generate samples from some univariate distribution and want to compute the quantiles from the learned distribution. At the moment I do not see any other option than sampling from the GAN and taking empirical quantiles or fitting a KDE to sampled data and taking the quantile thereof. I would be grateful for any paper suggestions dealing with this issue.

Comment: https://openreview.net/forum?id=BygMAiRqK7 perhaps